# Start loop to a specific indice when use list of array keys in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, key, indices

I need to manipulate the keys of an array, so I am using the following loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(aaa bbb ccc ddd)
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
        content="${array[i]}"
        echo "$i - $content"
done
```

With result:

```
0 - aaa
1 - bbb
2 - ccc
3 - ddd
```

But what if I need to start the loop at a specific index ?

If I didn't loop through the indices, the syntax would be:

```
for i in "${!array[@]:2}"; do
        content="${array[i]}"
        echo "$i - $content"
done
```

The expected result should be:

```
2 - ccc
3 - ddd
```

But instead I have this error:

```
line 4: aaa bbb ccc ddd: bad substitution
```

Is there a way to obtain the expected result ?

edit:
I use to do this:

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
        [[ $i -lt 2 ]] && continue
        content="${array[i]}"
        echo "$i - $content"
done
```

The problem is if the key is not 2 but 256423, it's take a while to start the loop.

Comment: Since you have arrays and not associative arrays, you don't have _keys_, you have _indices_. Do you really plan to model an array with 256423 elements using bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just start your index at a defined position:

```
for ((i=2; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do echo "$i - ${array[i]}"; done
```

```
2 - ccc
3 - ddd
```

Comment: I was trying exactly the same way on my machine before posting the message :) :)

Comment: Sure, simple. I forgot I can use C style, I'm too used to bash.
Thank you!